# How Wordpress should be runned on Docker

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker

I am very newbie on all of this stuff of Docker. I've read on some sites that should exist one image per each application is running. This means that for run wordpress I would need at least 2 images: One for MySQL and another for Wordpress (and apache). In fact, the official Wordpress docker image does not include MySQL, requires an external connection.

But I've found some images in which MySQL is embedded on the image among wordpress and Apache. This gives you a more portable image because you only need that to deploy on any server. But if in the system is already running an image of docker you are wasting resources.

So, my question is if Wordpress should be runned on a same image with MySQL or not. And if not, how it should be done to move all data on MySQL to a different location.

Answer (score 0):

The standart way is having a container per service, so you will have a container for MySQL and another one for Apache/PHP with the application.

If your are going to use the official MySQL container, and you want to persist the data, you just can to mount a volume from your host to the datadir in the mysql container:

```
$ docker run --name some-mysql -v /my/own/datadir:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:tag
```

This will create a folder in the `/my/own/datadir` path of your host with all the content of MySQL.

You can find more information about that in that link:

https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/mysql#where-to-store-data